# A doubt about the correspondence theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $f$ be a ring homomorphism from $R$ onto $R_1$. Then there is a one one correspondence between the set of all ideals of $R_1$ and the set of all ideals of $R$ that contain the kernel. Now what problem arises if I replace ideal by subring?

Comment: Are you implicitly assuming that $R1$ is a quotient ring of $R$?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa It would seem he is: "...from $R$ **onto** $R_1$."

Comment: @DerekAllums, good, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The correspondence theorem also holds for subrings. So subrings of the image correspond to subrings between the kernel and $R$. I believe the proof for groups or for ideals work with a few slight modifications.

Comment: Yeah, I also completed the proof . But then why is specifically ideal considered in the correspondence theorem? Why not subring?

Comment: @RioDutta Probably because the subring version doesn't give you a nice geomtric interpretation when you apply $\text{Spec}(\cdot)$ to both sides.

Comment: I didn't really understand your explanation. Can you give me much simpler view or tell me more clearly about Spec?

Comment: @RioDutta Unfortunately, if you haven't seen it before, it's probably a bit much to describe in a single comment, or chain of comments. Here's a good write-up to get you started on the relationship between (prime) ideals and varieties, though: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/11/30/the-ideal-variety-correspondence/

Comment: @RioDutta There are two correspondence theorems. One for subrings and another for ideals.

Comment: I didn't know that. Can you please give me any reference?

Comment: @RioDutta https://simomaths.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/introduction-to-ring-theory-5/. I have only ever used the ideal version.